# Video is not getting played using video.js

Tags: html, html5-video, video.js

Below is the html code which i am using to play videos in my video folder using video.js link

```
<!DOCTYPEs>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <video id="sample" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
            data-setup="{}">
            <source src="/video/video1.mp4"  type='video/mp4' target="_blank"/>
            <track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
        </video>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in browser console? Is the video path correct? Is the video file accessible?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write in what browser are you trying to make the code work. Is it possible that your browser doesn't support the video format? Chrome supports .mp4, but for example Firefox doesn't, it supports .webm.

You can read more about this in the [WebPlatform Docs](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/video)